# Monitor Container Load Average with Grafana Agent and Cadvisor (Docker Integration)

Tags: docker, grafana, cadvisor, grafana-agent

I’ve configured Docker integration on Grafana Cloud, utilizing Cadvisor and Grafana Agent to monitor Docker containers, and it’s been effective for most metrics. I’ve been referencing the metrics documented:
[Docker Integration Metrics.](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/monitor-infrastructure/integrations/integration-reference/integration-docker/#metrics)

However, I’m encountering challenges when trying to monitor the load average of individual containers. Specifically, the
`container_cpu_load_average_10s` 
metric appears in Grafana, but it doesn’t seem to provide any values.

I’m aware that load average is typically a host-level metric, but I’m interested in approximating it for my containers.

I came across these discussions related to the issue:

- [Issue 3706](https://github.com/grafana/agent/issues/3706)
- [Issue 1656](https://github.com/grafana/agent/issues/1656)

Could someone please advise if there have been any recent developments on this topic? Is there a way to pass the load average metric to Grafana Agent for my Docker containers, or can you suggest an approach to approximate it using the existing setup?

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or recommendations on how to achieve this monitoring goal. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at a [help/on-topic]. Your question being about configuration is not really suitable for this side. Consider asking it on [devops.se] or [sf] instead.